# How do you make a list of ints within a class Python

Tags: python, list

for some reason this code throws this error:

player.py:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.collisionXY[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

error:

```
line 21, in __init__
self.collisionXY[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
AttributeError: 'player' object has no attribute 'collisionXY'
```

what i want is to store the x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinates of a colliding rect as ints within the collisionXY list how can the code be fixed to do this

Comment: You're trying to create a set, not a list.  List syntax is `[ ]`

Comment: true true such a simple mistake ill change the code and get back to you thanks

Comment: Just `self.collisionXY = [0]*16`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a list to that variable, it would be

```
self.collisionXY = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

or just

```
self.collisionXY = [0]*16
```

When you write

```
self.collisionXY[16] =...
```

that is interpreted as trying to write to index 16 in `self.collisionXY`, which generates an error because `self.collisionXY` hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an array of 16 ints initialize to 0.

You can either use a list

```
self.collisionXY = [0]*16
```

a tuple:

```
self.collisionXY = (0,)*16
```

or an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

```
import array
...
self.collisionXY = array.array('l', [0]*16)
```